# Android OpenGL skybox light not really working

Tags: android, opengl-es, light

Okay, I have made a "skybox" (it's actually 5 plane, because of the different textures). It's works fine, but there is a problem with the lightning. It's not my strongest point in OpenGL, so I will be not surprised if the answer is not so hard.

So that is my start position view. As you can see the front plane is bright, but the left, top, right are not really, and there is a border between them and the front.

http://img696.imageshack.us/img696/3673/light01.png

When I go to the absolute center (nearly) of the skybox then the border are not so visible (I guess at the absolute center there is no border.

http://img233.imageshack.us/img233/2949/light02.png

First I tried with one light at the posistion (0,0,0) with these settings, but nothing, I tried to change the ambient, the diffuse, but not really helps:

```
    private float[] lightAmbient = {0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1.0f};
    private float[] lightDiffuse = {1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f};
    private float[] lightPosition = {0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};

    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DITHER);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_TEXTURE_2D);
            gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
            gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);

            gl.glClearDepthf(1.0f);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
            gl.glDepthFunc(GL10.GL_LEQUAL);
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHT0);
            gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
            gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_AMBIENT, lightAmbientBuffer);
            gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_DIFFUSE, lightDiffuseBuffer);
            gl.glLightfv(GL10.GL_LIGHT0, GL10.GL_POSITION, lightPositionBuffer);
    }

    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
            gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_LIGHTING);

            GLU.gluLookAt(gl, eyeX, eyeY, eyeZ, centerX, centerY, centerZ, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    }

    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
            if(height == 0) {
                height = 1;                         
            }

            gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
            GLU.gluPerspective(gl, 65.0f, (float)width / (float)height, 1.0f, 80.0f);
            gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
            gl.glLoadIdentity();
    }
```

So the question is how can I make this to work in every place where I am. I hope someone can help me, because now it's not really looking nice (without light is good, but I don't really want a night scene, ecspecially with a texture where there is the sun :).

**EDIT (how it works now)**: as it was in the answer there are no normals for the skybox anymore, but after I have enabled lightning I was needed to add this line to the code, and now it works like a charm, and the sky is bright everywhere.

```
    gl.glLightModelf(GL10.GL_LIGHT_MODEL_TWO_SIDE, GL10.GL_TRUE);
```

Comment: Why aren't you making your world inside a sphere? That would take away the whole lighting problem if you define correct normals for every vertex in the sphere.

Comment: Hmm. It's actually not a bad idea, maybe if there will be no really answer until tomorrow, then I will try it out. What' the problem is, that I don't really know how to create a sphere. (Maybe I do one in Blender and somehow import it, because manually I dont really know how can man do that.)

Comment: There are manual ways to achieve that (with some work). Check out this: http://www.swiftless.com/tutorials/opengl/sphere.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is indeed not so hard; you simply shouldn't use lighting at all on your skybox.

Comment: Thanks, now it's good, but there is another problem. Now the front sky are really dark, but the back is going brighter as I go away from it, towards the front. On the left and the right sides the light is gradient. Where they connect with the back they are as bright as the back plane, but where they connect with the front they are dark. I really can't understand what's going on :)

Comment: I have edited my own question how I was able to solve this problem.